# PlayFramework with Scala and Morphia

Tags: scala, mongodb, morphia

I keep getting this exception:

Oops: CannotCompileException
An unexpected error occured caused by exception CannotCompileException:
[source error] ds() not found in models.dc

What is wrong with my code?

Here is models.ds

```
package models

import com.google.code.morphia.annotations._

@Embedded
class ds{

  @Indexed
  var xs : Double=0

  @Indexed
  var xc : Double=0

  @Indexed
  var ys : Double=0

  @Indexed
  var yc : Double=0

  @Indexed
  var zs : Double=0

  @Indexed
  var zc : Double=0
}
```

Here is models.dc

```
package models

import com.google.code.morphia.annotations.{Embedded, Entity, Indexed}

@Entity
class dc{

  @Indexed
  var name : String = null

  @Embedded
  var summary : ds = new ds()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never Mind.
Because I was using the Play Framework Morphia Module,
I forgot to extend Model.

This is what caused the error.

Can anyone explain why this happened?

Comment: Hi do you mean you get PlayMorphia module work with Scala without problem?